# Novice question regarding manim and png images

Tags: python, manim

I'm new to coding and am trying to learn manim, which I'm using on my macbook pro. I'm trying to create a scene where manim draws a png file I saved. I saved the png file as "shirt.png" in my manim folder. I then ran the following code:

```
from manimlib.imports import *

class OutFit(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        
        shirt = ImageMobject("shirt")
        
        self.play(Write(shirt))
```

I've looked up several ways of how to get manim to do images and some solutions, but since I'm pretty new at this I don't always understand the answers I've found from other people's issues or if it applies to mine. I keep getting this error response:

raise IOError("File {} not Found".format(file_name))
OSError: File shirt not Found

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it should be `shirt = ImageMobject("shirt.png")` you have to specify the file type, if this doesn't work. get the full directory. eg
`/users/programs/shirt.png`

Comment: Thank you for the response. So, what does it mean if it says this:  "DrawBorderThenFill only works for VMobjects"
Exception: DrawBorderThenFill only works for VMobjects

Comment: `ImageMobject` is not a `VMobject`, `VMobjects` are Bezier curves, that is, vector curves, while `ImageMobject` is a bitmap (raster image).